# Trying to make buzzer work for TI CC2650 SensorTag

Tags: c, embedded, system

```
#include <ti/sysbios/family/arm/cc26xx/Power.h>
#include <ti/sysbios/family/arm/cc26xx/PowerCC2650.h>
#include <driverLib/timer.h>

 Task_Struct taskStruct;
    void taskFxn(UArg a0, UArg a1);
    PIN_init(BoardGpioInitTable);

    Task_Params params;
    Task_Params_init(&params);
    params.priority = TASK_PRI;
    params.stackSize = TASK_STACK_SIZE;
    params.stack = taskStack;

    Task_construct(&taskStruct, taskFxn, &params, NULL);

    BIOS_start();

    bool timerEnabled = 0;

    PIN_Config pwmExamplePins[] = {
    Board_LED1       | PIN_GPIO_OUTPUT_EN | PIN_GPIO_LOW   | PIN_PUSHPULL | PIN_DRVSTR_MAX,
    Board_LED2       | PIN_GPIO_OUTPUT_EN | PIN_GPIO_LOW   | PIN_PUSHPULL | PIN_DRVSTR_MAX,
    Board_KEY_SELECT | PIN_INPUT_EN       | PIN_HYSTERESIS | PIN_HYSTERESIS | PIN_PULLUP | PIN_IRQ_NEGEDGE,
    PIN_TERMINATE };

    PIN_State  pinState;
    PIN_Handle pinHandle;

    static void timerInitialize() {
    TimerConfigure(GPT0_BASE, TIMER_CFG_SPLIT_PAIR|TIMER_CFG_A_PWM);
    TimerLoadSet(GPT0_BASE, TIMER_A, TIMER_LOADSET);
    TimerMatchSet(GPT0_BASE, TIMER_A, TIMER_MATCH);

    //Stall timer when halting debugger
    //TimerStallControl(GPT0_BASE, TIMER_A, true)
    }

    static void pinCallBack(PIN_Handle handle, PIN_Id pinId) {

    if( timerEnabled) {
       timerEnabled = 0;

       // Allow standby in TI RTOS and stop timer
       Power_releaseConstraint(Power_SB_DISALLOW);
       TimerDisable(GPT0_BASE, TIMER_A);

    }
    else {
       timerEnabled = 1;

       // Disallow standby in TI RTOS to allow timer to run
       Power_setConstraint(Power_SB_DISALLOW);
       TimerEnable(GPT0_BASE, TIMER_A);
    }



    void taskFxn(UArg a0, UArg a1) {

    // Register client for pins in pwmExamplePins array
    pinHandle = PIN_open(&pinState, pwmExamplePins);
    // Route LED1 pin on SmartRF06EB to IO event port 0 (0 = Timer0A, 1 = Timer0B, 2 = Timer1A..)
    PINCC26XX_setMux(pinHandle, PIN_ID(Board_LED1), IOC_PORT_MCU_PORT_EVENT0);

    PIN_registerIntCb(pinHandle, pinCallBack);

    // Turn on PERIPH power domain and clock for GPT0
    Power_setDependency(PERIPH_GPT0);

    timerInitialize();

    // 100ms
    uint32_t sleepTicks = 100 * 1000/Clock_tickPeriod;

    bool ledValue = 0;

    while(1) {

      // Let task sleep, chip will go into IDLE or STANDBY mode depending on whether timer is enabled
      Task_sleep(sleepTicks);

      PIN_setOutputValue(pinHandle, PIN_ID(Board_LED2), ledValue);
      // Invert LED value
      ledValue = (ledValue ? 0 : 1);

  }
```

Trying to make buzzer work for the CC2650STK SensorTag Texas Instruments device from an example, but it keeps giving the same error and not able to continue further.

> fatal error #1965: cannot open source file
>   "ti/sysbios/family/arm/cc26xx/Power.h"

Is there some file missing from the device itself or should something be downloaded as an extra to continue?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried asking on TI forums?

Comment: I've been working on the cc2650 SensorTag for the past few weeks and have discovered that they don't make it very newb friendly lol. Getting System_printf() calls working and have ble working at the same time has been difficult. This comment was more of a vent than an actual comment obviously.